# Looking for Facebook Graph API to display audience name/info for campaign

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking to get the audience name/info from a campaign, however I cant seem to find any information regarding this.

Their API documentation sucksss! Does anyone have any pointers they can throw to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i was using the wrong thing. I was looking to use graph.facebook.com/[vers]/[act_id]/campaign? when I should have been using graph.facebook.com/[vers]/[act_id]/adsets?